# Using Mailgun Api in local Xamp Environment to fetch events

Tags: php, rest, mailgun

I have a question related to mailgun api. I am new to php and I encountered a very weird problem. basically when I try to use the code in the documentation of Mailgun to fetch the events from the website in my php application I get nothing, or in other cases when i print the result I get "Mailgun Magnificent API with response code of 200". When I use postman with the same url and use HTML basic authentication method I get the json with no problem.

When I checked the request on network monitor in Firefox dev edition I found out that the file is declared as /localhost/mailgun (mailgun is the name of the folder i created for the project) and the request is GET.[image]

I do not understand how am I suppose to send a GET request to mailgun through the API and mail gun open source dependencies while I am in a local environment.

How can I fetch events just by using mailgun api? I do not understand why their documentation code does not simply work.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;



# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-XXX');
$domain = 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/myapp.name.com';
$queryString = array(
    'begin'        => 'Fri, 3 May 2013 09:00:00 -0000',
    'ascending'    => 'yes',
    'limit'        =>  25,
    'pretty'       => 'yes',
    'subject'      => 'test'
);

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->get("$domain/events", $queryString);
```

Comment: the GET request you see in network is actually of the page you loaded in browser, not the request made by API

Comment: Did you tried this: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php#debugging